# Installing Nagios on Ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: server, nagios3

I am trying to get Ubuntu 18.04 installed in order to run Nagios on it
Problems start with a total lack of knowledge of Ubuntu Server - I have used Ubuntu desktop in the distant past - not that that helps very much
But

1. Have I been correctly informed that Nagios will not run in a desktop environment - hence needs Server to run
2. Whilst Server is apparently now installed (it claims to be...) on reboot - it is frozen at [seed=/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net][dsmode=net] up 20.33 seconds

I have no idea what this means - but my installation has been frozen for 10 minutes
This is the fifth time that I have gotten this far with the same result

PLEASE, PLEASE, PLEASE HELP ME - I am so fed up with Ubuntu server

Comment: cd /tmp
wget -O nagioscore.tar.gz https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nagioscore/archive/nagios-4.4.5.tar.gz
tar xzf nagioscore.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to install Nagios Core over the Shell of Ubuntu? And if you download your own Nagios Server, you have to visit it with its IP address which will be given to you after installing Nagios Core, so it won't run in a desktop variation. You can find the IP address in the ifconfig. If you need the download link, it is here: [https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/nagios-core-installing-nagios-core-from-source-96.html#Ubuntu](https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/nagios-core-installing-nagios-core-from-source-96.html#Ubuntuhttps://)